# How do I remove an action hook by s2member

Tags: hooks, actions, s2member

I noticed that my plugin doesnt work when s2member is activated but unfortunately it is needed for the site functionality, i did some research if I comment out this line on hooks.inc.php then my plugin works, how can I remove it from my plugin ? because once s2member is updated it removes my // and we are back with the same issue. this is the line:

```
//add_action("wp_login", "c_ws_plugin__s2member_login_redirects::login_redirect", 10, 2);
```

I looked up the codex and found this function :

```
<?php remove_action( $tag, $function_to_remove, $priority ); ?>
```

would that work for what I am trying to accomplish and if so can you show me how to implement it please? any suggestions/help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this using this  code :

```
remove_action("wp_login", "c_ws_plugin__s2member_login_redirects::login_redirect", 10, 2);
```

which I added inside my custom plugin file.